# I'm trying to connect some macOS computers to a Windows Server file server but it gives me a connection error, what could it be happening?

Tags: networking, macos, mac, file-server, windows-server-2022

I have a brand new Windows Server 2022 working as a file server, it works fine when I try to use the file server from Windows and Linux computers, but I'm having a problem with any macOS computer that tries to connect to this file server it gives me a error:

> There was a problem connecting to the server "SERVER IP."

I've tried to enable SMBv1 and SMBv2, but it still give me this error only on macOS.

On my network I have another file servers where the macOS computer can connect without any problem.

I want to know if this can be something that I can configure on my Windows Server to allow this connection from this macOS computer?

Comment: Try to temporarily disable the firewall on the Windows server and test.

Comment: The firewall on Windows Server was alredy disabled, and it still got this error, I even unnistallen any third party software like my antivirus to test it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Check what you did against this article : https://techwiser.com/access-windows-shared-folders-from-a-mac/